# How to add all currently misspelled words to Vim's spell list?

Tags: vim

I have a file that contains many words Vim doesn't know. I know `zg` can add a single word, but is there a way to add all "misspelled" words to Vim's dictionary?

Comment: No, there is no dedicated command for that. The best you can do with what you have is to repeat a macro that moves the cursor to the next misspelled word with `]s` and adds it to the list with `zg` a large number of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on romainl's comment. You can create a macro that calls itself:

```
qqq        " clear register q
qq]szg@q   " create a macro in register q that steps to the next spelling mistake
           " add it to the wordbook and call the macro at q (currently empty)
@q         " call the macro at the register q
```

You see, even though, register q is empty at the time you define your macro, it will be read at execution time. So as soon as you call your now defined macro, it will call itself.